# how to access ActionBar in android using application context

Tags: android

I need to access action bar items for the whole application at one place,it is possible to access action bar using application context in android?

Comment: No, you need the corresponding Activity where the ActionBar is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just make that MenuItem (or something else on ActionBar) public and static.

I do this on one of my project, sounds not brilliant, but works.

BTW, you can access them only in UI thread...

Comment: maintaining static references for UI elements is a bad idea as Context is associated with every View and thus leads to context leakages...